# How to calculate the turning number of a specific curve?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to calculate the winding number of $ \gamma(t)= e^\frac{i-1}{1-t} $ on the intervall $[0,1-\delta]$, $ \delta > 0 $ around 0. The derivative I got is $ \gamma'(t)= e^\frac{i-1}{1-t}\frac{(i-1)}{(1-t)^2}$. Plugging this in the Definition of winding number, I get
$$  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{1-\delta} \frac{1}{\gamma(t)}\gamma'(t) \, dt = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{1-\delta} \frac{i-1}{(1-t)^2} \, dt. $$
This is where i stuck. I have always an $ i $ left, which can not be correct since the winding number is always an integer.

Comment: why is $\gamma$ closed? the winding number is an integer for closed curves

Comment: You are right... Is there any other way to show that the curve wind infintley often around 0 ?

Comment: the integral is $c/\delta-b$ so obviously, it is unbounded, hence the curve turns infinitely many times as $\delta \to 0$

Comment: I do not understand... what is c and b and which integral do you mean?

Comment: $c,b$ are non-zero constants from the argument change integral you wrote, namely $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{1-\delta}\frac{i-1}\int_0^{1-\delta} \frac{i-1}{(1-t)^2}dt=\frac{1}{2\pi i}(\frac{i-1}{\delta}-(i-1))$

Comment: Sorry, but how does it tell me, that it winds infintley often around 0? Your argument is right, that $ \gamma $ is not closed, so I can not apply the above formula ...

Comment: why not - the formula is correct for any curve, it just gives its argument change which of course may not be an integer; but if it is unbounded, it means it must wind infinitely many times around zero as $\delta \to 0$ as one turn is worth at most $2\pi$ in absolute value; so if it would turn finitely many times, the argument would stay bounded